# How can I generate a completely balanced combination

Tags: r, sampling, combinatorics, permutation-test, rotation

Attaching a code that generates unique combinations of 8 letters but, it still lacks a condition wherein all letters should have equal counts per column. For my code, basically, letter a to h should show 26 times per column.

`options(max.print=999999999)
product <- c("a", "b", "c","d","e","f","g","h")
p <- length(product)
fin=unique(t(sapply(1:208, function(x) sample(product, p))))
nrow(fin) == factorial(p)
fin`

Comment: Are the letters definitely unique?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095992/generating-all-distinct-permutations-of-a-list-in-r

Comment: ... But if what you want is to generate latin squares, rather ask about that ...

Comment: @AccidentalStatistician yes they're all unique

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot!

```
def all_permutations(prefix, lst):
    if 0==len(lst):
        yield prefix
    else:
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            all_permutations(prefix+lst[i], lst[:i]+lst[i+1:])
```